# problem in displaying pie chart

Tags: visualforce

Controller:

```
public with sharing class combiningtwolistController1 {
    public List < AggregateResult > groupedResults1 {get;set;}
    public List < AggregateResult > groupedResults2 {get;set;}
    public class Item {
        public String label {get;set;}
        public Integer data {get;set;}
        public Item(String label, Integer data) {
            this.label = label;
            this.data = data;
        }
    }
    public List < Item > getItems() {
        Item[] items = new Item[] {};
        groupedResults1 = [select count(id) total, Account.name name from contact where Account.name != null group by Account.name];
        system.debug('groupedResults1 ' + groupedResults1);
        groupedResults2 = [select count(id) total, Account.name name from contact where Account.name = null group by Account.name];
        system.debug('groupedResults2' + groupedResults2);
        list < AggregateResult > result = new list < AggregateResult > ();
        result.addAll(groupedResults1);
        result.addAll(groupedResults2);
        for (AggregateResult ar: result) {
            system.debug('ar' + ar);
            //List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id FROM Account];
            //Integer con = [select count() from contact where AccountId in :acc];
            if ((ar.get('total') != null)) {
                items.add(new Item((String) ar.get('name'), (Integer) ar.get('total')));
            } else {


            }
        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="combiningtwolistController1">
    <apex:chart data="{!items}" height="400" width="380">
        <apex:pieSeries labelField="label" dataField="data">
            <apex:chartLabel display="rotate" field="data" />
        </apex:pieSeries>
    </apex:chart>
</apex:page>
```

i am trying to displaying pie chart using the above,it is not getting displayed.not showing any error,i am unable to get vats wrong with my code,please suggest me am a fresher,thanks in advance.

Comment: i think,the problem is with groupedresult2,pie chart is not binding because of the null names,how to resoilve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably simplest to just use one query and replace the null name with a hard-coded string of your choosing:

```
for (AggregateResult ar : [
        select count(id) total, Account.name name
        from contact
        group by Account.name
        ]) {
    String name = (String) ar.get('name');
    Integer total = (Integer) ar.get('total');
    items.add(new Item(name != null ? name : 'No Account Defined', total));
}
```

The total will never be null.

Comment: i tried your code ,Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [List<sahi.combiningtwolistController1.Item>].add(String, Integer) ,this error got,

Comment: @sahi See changed answer.